# Не могу написать тест на создание поста. (DRF)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pytest

У меня есть тест на get запрос о списке всех постов, он прекрасно работает. Но я не могу сделать post запрос на создание тех самых постов. По началу была проблема в том что я не мог авторизоваться, но этот недочёт с моей стороны уже был исправлен. Сейчас вместо статус кода 403 я уже получаю 400, как я понимаю я неправильно передаю какие-то данные, но авторизоваться у меня получилось. Ниже код моих тестов

**Это рабочий тест(GET)**

```
    @pytest.mark.django_db
def test_authorized_post_list_request(api_client_with_credentials):
    response = api_client_with_credentials.get("/api/post/")
    assert Post.objects.count() == 0
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

**Это на post**

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_authorized_post_creation(api_client_with_credentials):
    data = {
        "title": "string",
        "body": "string"
    }
    response = api_client_with_credentials.post("/api/post/", data=data)
    assert response.status_code == 201
```

**conftest.py**

```
@pytest.fixture
def api_client_with_credentials(db, create_user, api_client):
    user = create_user()
    api_client.force_authenticate(user=user)
    yield api_client
    api_client.force_authenticate(user=None)
```